# Unable to uncheck checkbox from chrome

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I am trying to check/uncheck a checkbox/radiobutton both from the table cell as well as the actual checkbox /radiobutton

I have written this below code to select a checkbox/radiobutton from table cell 
Please refer code pen for actuall code.

The code works fine for IE 11 browser but not in Chrome. If i select the table cell then the checkbox is selected but in chrome when i check on the actual check box nothing happens .

I think it is the checkbox internally calls the PropagateBelow method.

[Check/Uncheck check box for chrome(Select on the CHECKBOX itself on TABLE CELL works fine)](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJWeqN)

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td onclick="PropagateBelow(this);" style="width:100px;">
                <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="Test123" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

```
function PropagateBelow(tableCell) {
    alert(tableCell);
    var radioButtons = tableCell.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i < radioButtons.length; i++) {
        var radioButton = radioButtons[i];
        if (radioButton != null && radioButton != undefined) {
            if (radioButton.type == 'radio' || radioButton.type == 'checkbox') {
                radioButton.click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Chrome you are using?
I am using "43.0.2357.124 m", your code work fine.

Comment: are you expecting to have multiple radio buttons in the cell?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what the exact misbehavior is you're observing. What happens when I test your code is that when clicking the cell, `PropagateBelow(this)` is called which activates/deactivates the checkbox, based on its current state. When I click the checkbox, the checkbox is ticked, but then the click event bubbles up, again triggering `PropagateBelow(this)` which in turn unticks the checkbox again.

If you want to prevent that, you have to stop the propagation of the event when you click on the checkbox, like

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td onclick="PropagateBelow(this);" style="width:100px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="Test123" onclick="cancelPropagation();" />
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

and then implement `cancelPropagation()` as follows

```
function cancelPropagation(ev){
  var event = ev || window.event;
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
}
```

Here's your modified codepen project: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwEpxm

*As mentioned, I'm not sure I got what you mean. If this doesn't help, let me know, so I'll delete my answer again :)*

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a JavaScript function to propagate the click to all of the radio buttons, you can wrap the radio button in label which takes up the whole space of the table cell. Wrapping a radio button in a label will allow you to click anywhere in the label to toggle the radio button without having to use any JavaScript.

Please see example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJMWzb

```
<table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;">
                  <label style="width:100%;height:100%;display:block;">  
                    <input type="checkbox" id="test" value="Test123" />
                  </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Funnily enough this does work fine for me in Chrome, but as a general rule it's better to set the `checked` property to `true` on checkboxes instead of trying to simulate clicks.

This could simply be done by replacing `radioButton.click();` with `radioButton.checked = true;`, or if you wanted to toggle the checkbox `radioButton.checked = !radioButton.checked;`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/checked

Comment: the problem is that if you click on the radio button itself nothing happens